# executing a one time javascript code after authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication

After authentication, the server side code either goes to a default page or goes to the original page on which the user had clicked before authentication. In all cases, the page is rendered after a redirect (I am using django). In this case, how do you execute a one time javascript code on the rendered page? One way I can think of is to add a "parameter" that indicates to the page being rendered that the one time code should be executed. The "onload" function can then check and execute the code. Is there any other, "more elegant" way?

Comment: What do you mean "one time"?  As in the code only occurs the first time the user sees the page, and if they reload the page, the code will not execute?

Comment: Is this like showing a `Welcome back!` banner?

Comment: @Ivan - yes the code should get executed only once but on the browser side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set a cookie or add a class on the body with Django. On the client side you simply check if the cookie or the class is present. In case of the cookie it would be best to delete it with JavaScript.

Comment: that makes sense - I could execute the code and then delete the cookie from client side.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you're describing is within the acceptable range of elegance. Anyway, another approach is to use cookies:

The authentication page will set a cookie, the page you land at (after authentication) will check this cookie. If it's there it will run this 'one time' code and clear the cookie.